# How do I hide the label of disabled field groups?

Tags: 9

In the Manage Display tab, I have disabled fields because they are rendered in the page.html.twig file inside of a region. I don't want the field to display the label.

I can set the label to hidden for the non-disabled fields, but for the disabled ones, when I change the label to "- Hidden -" it simply reverts itself back to "Above"

Here is the field before clicking save:

[image: Label for image before save]

Here it is after save:

[image: Label for image after save]

Here it is rendered on the page with the annoying label that I want to hide:

[image: Image with annoying label that I want to hide.]

Comment: The field is disabled and therefore the settings don't matter in that case. The field should be enabled, and the label set to hidden. This would be averted by using a view mode and either placing a Views block or programatically creating a render array in the page preprocess hook.